# What is the font used in scala logo

Tags: font-identification

I am trying to create scala logo in HTML however could not find the font for the logo. Can someone help me with it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Museo Slab**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/exljbris/museo-slab/)

Looks to be the 900 weight as well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @scott would love to know how to figure it out from image ?

Comment: I have the font and recognized the S, l, and c. Characters in a typeface can often have very unique aspects to them. That rounded bottom l with the slab top is a dead giveaway for Museo Slab. The S and c simply confirmed it.

Comment: Hey is there any free alternative available for it ?

Comment: Doubtful, but I wouldn't know. It's only $16.50 for Museo Slab 900 though.

Comment: Some weights of Museu are free: http://www.exljbris.com/museoslab.html but as Scott says, it's only $16. That's practically free.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar: Amasis-MT-Std-Black
http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Amasis-MT-Std-Black/download